# What is the relationship between covering space and group?

Tags: algebraic-topology

An example the seguent question

> Let A and B two point of $\mathbb{S^2}$. Does exist a connected
>   covering space with degree 2 of the topological space
>   $\mathbb{S^2}\setminus\ \left \{A,B \right \}$?

I know that $\mathbb{S^2}$ less two points is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R^2}$ less one point so the foundamental group is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.
Can i finish the exercise answering yes and showing $G=<2>$ because $[\mathbb{Z}:G]=2$?

What happens if we are considering $\mathbb{S^3}$?
What is the relationship between degree of the cover and index of subgroup?

Comment: You should invoke the classification theorem of covering spaces.
All hypothesis are satisfied and hence a degree 2 connected covering space exists if and only if there exists a subgroup of index 2 in the fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part: Yes, you are right. If you want to be more explicit you could use the two-fold covering $p:ℝ^2\setminus0 → ℝ^2 \setminus0, x ↦ x^2$.

The 3-sphere $\mathbb{S}^3$ is simply connected, even after taking out points. This means the fundamental group $π_1(\mathbb{S}^3\setminus P, *) = 0$. Here $P$ is an (automatically finite) discrete set of points and $*$ some basepoint.

[The classification theorem](http://planetmath.org/classificationofcoveringspaces) mentioned by Mohamed Hashi tells us:

> Equivalence classes of based coverings (with a connected total space) are in bijective correspondence with subgroups of the fundamental group $π_1(\mathbb{S}^3\setminus P, *)$

As the trivial group $0$ has no nontrivial subgroups, you can't get any nontrivial coverings.